# javascript error 'email' is not defined.[no-undef]

Tags: javascript, html

javascript error 'email' is not defined.[no-undef]

```js
function confirmInput() {
  email = document.forms[0].email.value;
  alert("Hello " + email + "! You are now subscribet to our page");
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="confirmInput()" action="php/email.php" class="offer-form" method="post" name="validate">
        
            <input id="email" type="text" class="txtb" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" required>
            <input type="submit" class="sub" value="Submit">
```

Comment: I can see the code snippet is working fine. I ran the snippet gave a random email Id and I was been alerted correctly !

Comment: You haven't defined `email`. It needs to be `let email = ... ` (or `const` or even `var`)

Comment: thnx all the error is gone.

Comment: Since you got it working again I would advice that you perform some checks to see if the email is a valid email before submitting it. I.e. contains `@` and ends in `.something`. etc. You can find a regex on this pretty easily. You'll have to perform a check again server side for good measure, but a lot of the server side languages have predefined functions that you can utilize for that, thankfully.

Comment: @Martin the code is working,but i had the errors in dreamweaver.thnx

Answer (score 0):

Your variable email is not defined. This mean you should add var before email.

```
var email = document.forms[0].elements.namedItem("email").value;
```

Comment: i have an other error 'confirmInput' is defided but never used.[no-unused-vars]please

Comment: How I understand you use jslint and you can change settings
in your .jshintrc add "unused": false

Comment: i am using adobe dreamweaver,i dont now how to get off this error.'confirmInput' is defided but never used.[no-unused-vars]